# Вёрстка страницы по центру

Tags: html, css, javascript

Имеется следующее:

```
#pagecalc
    {   
        position:absolute;
        width:1905px;
        left:50%;
        margin-left:-953px;
    }
    #pagecalc #calcontent
    {
        position:absolute;
        width:100%;
        background-color:#333;
    }
```

Если уменьшать масштаб в браузере, блок всегда находится по центру страницы, это мне нужно. Но если начать увеличивать масштаб, простыми словами "приближать страницу" контент который находится в #pagecalc #calcontent уходит в лево за границу и его нельзя прокрутить, одним словом исчез, полоса скролл крутиться только в право. Как от этого избавиться?

Comment: %) Напишите или нарисуйте, что Вы хотите получить в итоге. Уточните вопрос.

Comment: По моему доступно объяснил :/

Comment: Объясние пожалуйста зачем используется свойство `position: absolute`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может просто:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #pagecalc {
        background-color: #fff;
    }
    #calcontent {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 1905px; /* Ширину можно поменять */
        background-color: #333;
    }
</style>
<div id="pagecalc">
    <div id="calcontent">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Так-же для блока `#calcontent` можно применить `max-width` и `min-width`, тогда контент который расположен по центру будет занимать размер от `min-width` до `max-width`